# Stopping to eat is tedious, is there any way to automate the process?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

While I've managed to optimize and automate almost everything, constantly having to stop and eat is annoying (I run around a lot, so I get hungry quickly). Is there any device or tool that will keep me well fed at all times without having to stop and feed?

Comment: I have to ask, if everything is automated, what do you do?

Comment: @Ender Automate *ALL THE THINGS*

Comment: The work will end when the process of automation itself is automated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wondering why your Quantum Helmet doesn't operate [as advertised](http://wiki.industrial-craft.net/index.php?title=Quantum_helmet#Additional_effects)? [As of IC2 v1.110](http://wiki.industrial-craft.net/index.php?title=Updates#v1.110.C2.A0.28IC.C2.B2.29), the Quantum Helmet can refill your hunger with carried canned food, at an EU cost of 10,000 EU per point. And, of course, at the cost of carrying said canned goods around.

Alternatively, you could look into foods with higher saturation. Ambrosia, crafted from bee products, gives high saturation (and 40 seconds of regeneration). Or, if you don't want to bother with that, steak is always a good option.

Comment: I forgot about that. Have set myself up a canning machine, and my helmet is now delivering it straight to my face.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I have not heard of anything that automatically makes you eat, but if you construct a level 4 pyramid with a beacon at the top you can insert a diamond, a gold/iron ingot or an emerald you can activate the regeneration buff. If you stay within the beacons range, it will keep regenerating your health so you don't need to eat.

Comment: That's cool, but the constant 'hits' you get at 0 hunger would be annoying.

Comment: And only works in the limited range of the beacon.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie of course!! You would have to do your work in the beacons range.