# What is the best way to eat automatically in direwolf20 1.7 pack?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-direwolf20

As the title says.

What is the best portable way to automatically eat?

I used to use the auto feeder from modular power suits but it no longer seems to be available or is disabled.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/107479

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IC2 [Quantum Helmet](http://wiki.industrial-craft.net/index.php?title=QuantumSuit_Helmet) will automatically feed you, provided that there's a suitable food source in your inventory. You'll need to [can your food](http://wiki.industrial-craft.net/index.php?title=Canning_Machine) in order for it to work.

Canning isn't a bad thing, it allows you to carry varied stacks of yummy goodness to suit your ever-changing nutritional needs as you age - I like exploring caves and staying regular is essential for doing that.

Since you're using the DW20 1.7 pack, your power generation is probably all RF, yet the IC2 machines require EU instead. Fear not, you can use a RedNet energy cable ([RedNet Cable](http://ftbwiki.org/RedNet_Cable), some electrum ingots and a redstone block) to bridge between RF -> EU to an IC2 [MFSU](http://wiki.industrial-craft.net/index.php?title=MFS_Unit). You'll need the MFSU to charge the helmet.

Don't directly power the machines from the MFSU unless you have some transformer upgrades in them, since the power coming out of the MFSU is at a much higher tier than the basic machines can take. You'll just want a few RedNet cables so you can power the MFSU and the machines, unless you want to build the upgrades or a transformer.

There's also a [solar variety](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Solar_Helmet), but while adding the convenience, it takes away quite a few of the cooler features.

If you're into Magic, Thaumic Explorer (for Thaumcraft) offers the Talisman Of Nourishment, which can consume simple foods in your hot bar and feed them to you. It won't work for anything that gives buffs / debuffs, and a quick Google search indicates that there are some unresolved crash bugs using it.